# How to manually add bootstrap and flat-ui to meteor application?

Tags: meteor

Whats the best way to add bootstrap to your meteor app the manual way?  I tried adding both the bootstrap-3 package and the flat-ui package the command line way.  And I see the folders created in my packages directory, but when I import my mocks they look nothing like what they should.  So I thought I would try to just add them manually.  Im guessing I can just put the main css files in the stylesheets directory.  Where should I put all the other stuff?  Help greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to integrate something like a https://wrapbootstrap.com template into your meteor app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the meteor app but to add bootstrap manually, I would do the following:

In your folder structure, create the following paths:
../../resources/css
../../resources/js

Add boostrap:
../../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css
../../resources/js/bootstrap.min.js

Then, you can include these in your .jsp or .aspx pages like so:
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
< script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/js/bootstrap.min.js">< /script>

My recommendation is to go with either bootstrap or flat-ui but not both. You can override the bootstrap classes yourself and customize them to give elements (e.g., buttons, drop-downs, etc.) a flatter look. You can do this by creating your custom **style.css** global style sheet and include it in your pages using the
< link > tag above. Then, ensure whatever you are using to build your application (ant, maven, etc.) accounts for the bootstrap resources.

Comment: In Meteor you don't need to add `<link rel...>` and `<script...>`. Meteor will automatically find all js and css files (excluding those in the `server` directory) and send them to the client. Also you shouldn't include both the full version and the minified version, or else you'll get both of them in the final app. It doesn't matter which you take, since Meteor minifies js/css in production mode anyway.